# Objection versioning database for enterprise apps

Tags: database-design

Many enterprise apps have relational database as back-end storage for objects.
Some objects are immutable, some not.

When immutable object depends on mutable it should provide appropriate version.

See: 
You have *Order* object and *Customer* object. Order depends on customer. But order never changes. After order is completed and shipped customer changes her address.
How can I know which address was used for shipping?
I do not want to store ALL information in order because it would unnormalize my database.

The answer is versioning: Order should depend on customer *with specific version*.

That is idea used for shared libraries (GAC, SxS, different .so versions and so on).

But how to do it in database?
Add "version" field to ALL tables and to any relation field? That would increase my database X2 and make it entangled.

Separate this info and store it somewhere?

I believe there has to be nice solution.
Do you know any?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand the problem.  Taking your example of customers and orders, for example, you could have

```
CREATE TABLE address (
  address_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  street     VARCHAR2(100),
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name  VARCHAR2(100),
  ...
  address_id  NUMBER REFERENCES address( address_id )
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  customer_id NUMBER REFERENCES customer( customer_id ),
  address_id  NUMBER REFERENCES address( address_id )
);
```

If `ADDRESS` is a first-class table, both `ORDERS` and `CUSTOMER` can reference a particular address.  `CUSTOMER` can reference the customer's current address, `ORDERS` can reference the address the order was chipped to which may have been the customer's then-current address or may have been the address of the person they were placing the order for (i.e. I place an order for flowers that I have sent to my mother's house on Mother's Day).  `ADDRESS` then becomes immutable so rather than updating an `ADDRESS` row, you would simply do an `INSERT` with a new `ADDRESS_ID` and update the row in the `CUSTOMER` table to point to the new `ADDRESS`.

If you want to track the history of a customer's addresses, you'd simply move the `address_id` out of the `customer` table and into a new `customer_address` mapping table that has some sort of version-related information.  Commonly, you would have something like this where you specify a range of dates where the mapping was valid.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_address (
  customer_address_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id         NUMBER REFERENCES customer( customer_id ),
  address_id          NUMBER REFERENCES address( address_id ),
  valid_from          DATE,
  valid_to            DATE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found out, immutable data should never be allowed to reference mutable data. The answer is **to make the referenced data immutable**. Using versions is just one example of doing that, but there are other ways.

In your Order-Customer example, the order is not dependent on the entire customer — changing the customer password, or creating new orders, should not affect the original order in any way. So, you can rip out the dependent parts out of the customer and make them immutable. This means that an Address is immutable, but you can still change a customer's reference to their current address or addresses because the customer is still mutable.

This can be implemented in several ways using a relational database. Two obvious ones:

- You can make the Address table insert-only (no updates or deletes). This is the easiest way, but might get in the way of your ORM, and keeps all Addresses in the database even if they are not associated with an Order.
- Keep the Address table mutable (updates and deletes allowed). You then create a copy of the customer's current Address whenever a new Order is created, and the Order references the new copy. This should be the ORM-friendliest solution, but every Order gets its own copy of the Address even if the Address never changes.